# Add Scroll bar with <accordation> in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am using  in AngularJs and was wondering how do I add vertical scroll bar using AngularJS.

```
 <accordion close-others="oneAtATime" class="side-setting">
        <accordion-group is-open="status.open1" ng-init="status.open1=true" ng-repeat="facet in facetslist">
            <accordion-heading>
                {{ facet.Title }} <i class="pull-right glyphicon" ng-class="{'fa fa-chevron-down': status.open1, 'fa fa-chevron-up': !status.open1}"></i>
            </accordion-heading>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="itm in facet.List">
                        <label class="control control--checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="" />{{ itm.Key }}<div class="control__indicator"></div>
                        </label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</accordion-group>
    </accordion>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unlikely to be useful to future users (the answer is trivial, and unrelated to most of the question text)

Comment: Disagree with you on this. It is useful for anyone to easily add scroll bar inside <accordion>. So will vote it positive.

Comment: Adding scrollbars works the same in literally any element, so I'm not sure why this one needs its own question; but it's up to the community to decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```